# Laptop (PC) turns itself on automatically

Tags: laptop, wake-up

I have a laptop (Win 10), and I always use Standby/Lid close for it. However, it randomly (especially on nights) turns on automatically (just the board; the screen is still off). Then it has intensive CPU load & noise. Even if I turn it off, very shortly after it again turns on. This also happens from hibernation.

- Nothing is set to "awaken this device" in `Device Manager`
- `powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` shows `none`.
- Event Viewer [shows not much information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfLg8.png)
- It is new laptop, is not dirty or clogged ( thanks for pointing to that  possible issue).

I've observed today and when I removed the power line and internet-cable, it didn't turn on automatically today.

---

p.s. "use shutdown" instead, is no way a solution.

Comment: Have you looked in the BIOS for power on settings like WOL, action on power loss. Also have a read of https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/31/find-pc-wakes-stop/

Comment: @davidgo answer would have been better i think, and i could also upvote your recommendation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment above. By the standards of the site my comment is not an answer because, while it hopefully pointed you in the correct direction it simply makes guesses. It would also largely be a "link only" answer which is frowned upon here. If you did find a solution yourself it is a good idea to post your solution as an answer and accept it so other people know what worked for you.

Comment: @davidgo I think that "Look into BIOS to check WOL" is one answer (yeah, shorter, but still valid answer). however, as you wish. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't comment:
Does the Laptop have some kind of connection to the internet?
If so, could it try to install updates?

How about the BIOS? Is "Wake On LAN" enabled?
If so, disabling it could help.

Why don't you shut it down normally?
What happens if you do that?

What about (as a last resort) removing the battery over night?

Edit to also have that mentioned:
Cleaning your Laptop if it's dusty will certainly help with the heat issues.
Maybe closing the lid is not recognized properly.

What is Task Manager reporting as high use of CPU or GPU?
Disable that program if at all possible.

In response to your PS:
Why is a complete shutdown not an option? Maybe you can accomplish what you want in another way, not involving your PC being on?

What happens if you only disconnect the network?

Answer (score 1):

You could turn if off completely when you want it off, instead of just closing the lid...

I'm guessing the "lid open" switch might be dirty, and reporting "open" sometimes even when closed. Or in case it was completely off, then the power button might be dirty or worn & shorting out.

And why would the laptop be "boiled up", it sounds like it's very hot? Maybe it really is very dirty & dusty, and cleaning out the vents & fans & switches would help.

Or if nothing else works, you could always shut it down and then remove the battery, that ought to stop it.